# Validation messages doesn't shows up

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I added validations to my `Movie` class, then I change flow of the program in my `MoviesController` and i added Validation Messages to my `.cshtml` but when I ran my application, validation messages doesn't shows up.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Movie movie)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (movie.Id == 0)
        {
            movie.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Movies.Add(movie);
        }
        else
        {
            var movieInDb = _context.Movies.Single(m => m.Id == movie.Id);

            movieInDb.Name = movie.Name;
            movieInDb.NumberInStock = movie.NumberInStock;
            movieInDb.ReleaseDate = movieInDb.ReleaseDate;
            movieInDb.GenreId = movie.GenreId;

            _context.Entry(movieInDb).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Movies");
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Movies");
    }
    var viewModel = new NewMovieViewModel
    {
        Genres = _context.Genres.ToList(),
        Movie = movie
    };

    return RedirectToAction("New", viewModel);
}
```

This is method in `MoviesController` where i changed the flow of the program.

`Movie` class and validations

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Genre")]
        [Required]
        public byte GenreId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Release date")]
        [Required]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Number in stock")]
        [Required]
        [Range(1,20)]
        public int NumberInStock { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And last `New.cshtml`

```
@model Vidly.VIewModels.NewMovieViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{
    if (Model.Movie != null)
    {
        <h2>Edit Movie</h2>
    }
    else
    {
        <h2>New Movie</h2>
    }

}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Movies"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Movie.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.ReleaseDate, "{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Movie.ReleaseDate)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.GenreId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Movie.GenreId, new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Movie.GenreId)

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movie.NumberInStock)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movie.NumberInStock, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Movie.NumberInStock)

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

    if(Model.Movie !=null){

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Movie.Id)
    }

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the [`Html.ValidationSummary(true);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method in the `New.chtml`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true);
    ...
}
```

And I suppose you should replace `return RedirectToAction("New", viewModel);` by `return View("New", viewModel);` to send not valid model data back to the `New()` action method to be able display error messages.

*NOTE:
If the `Html.ValidationSummary(...)` parameter is `true`, then only model-level errors are displayed. If the parameter is `false`, then all errors are shown.*

Comment: Solved my problem.